# understanding random graphs with specified degree distribution

Tags: random-graphs

I was self-reading this note [Random Graphs as models of networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0202208.pdf)
by Newman; Could anyone explain briefly what is happening in section $2$? I did not get the algorithm he described too. This may be due to my poor English understanding. It would be very helpful if one just explained the critical equations from this section.

And why will one be interested in building a random graph with specified degree distribution?

Many thanks.